# Filter objects by type in Outliner

Tags: objects, interface, outliner, object-mode

How can I filter objects by their types in Outliner? For example I want to show all the lights in the scene. This works for cameras, but not for lights:

[image]

Comment: weird, you should have lights in your list, what Blender version is it?

Comment: @moonboots 2.93

Comment: Oh it only shows the types of objects that actually exist in the scene... now I feel silly

Comment: mmh no it should show even though there is no light in your scene, at least it works this way in my Blender version, maybe it has changed...

Comment: I just checked 2.93.3 and it is definitely not showing Lights until I add a Light to the scene. My startup scene is completely empty and it's only showing Objects and Empties as options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 2.93.3, if you start with a completely empty scene, as my startup file does, the filter menu shows only Collections and Objects.  Other categories don't show up until you add something from that category to the scene.

EDIT: per comment from [brockman](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/31447/brockmann) this is intended behavior. [Git history](https://github.com/dfelinto/blender/blame/c4ef90f5a0b1d05b16187eb6e32323defe6461c0/release/scripts/startup/bl_ui/space_outliner.py#L402) of space_outliner.py, line 402 indicates that this has always been the behavior.

Comment: See `space_outliner.py`, line 402: There is a simple condition to check whether any *light data* is part of the blend. Same for armatures, meshes, cameras etc. so I guess this behavior is *intended*: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oEDiq.png